# Remove file created comments from netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have created Hibernate Mapping files and pojo from database sing netbeans. iT is successfully created but after creating it is having a comment like

```
// Generated Dec 5, 2011 11:29:31 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA
```

in my java file and hbm files.

Is there any option to remove this comments from my file in netbeans

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it would be a good idea to remove such a comment from your class. Down the line you or someone else might want to do some modifications and might forget/not be aware that the file was automatically generated. Re-generating the file will cause any of your changes to be overwritten which would mean you will spend more time fixing the problem.

Since you seem to be needing this change due to SVN issues, I suggest you remove the file from there.

Comment: Yah i know that but we have to change to change our database frquesntly. So each time we have created this pojo classes the comments will change and when we commit this in svn this will cuase for conflicts. I need to remove this conflicts for that we have to remove this comments.

Comment: To my knowledge, automatically generated files are usually kept out from SVN. Did you try that approach?

Comment: yup no need of this i have reverted the entire package.

Comment: Yah actually don't need to kept these files inside the svn.. Thanks

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your question, please mark the green 'very good' near it.